# Get all indexes for a python list

Tags: python

I can get the first index by doing:

```
l = [1,2,3,1,1]
l.index(1) = 0
```

How would I get a list of all the indexes?

```
l.indexes(1) = [0,3,4]
```

?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,1,1]
>>> [index for index, value in enumerate(l) if value == 1]
[0, 3, 4]
```