# Python - get index of list from which on all further entries satisfy condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

Imagine I have a list

```
l = [12,13,14,10,13,14]
```

and I want to find the index from which on all items are greater than `10` (in this case it is the index `4` corresponding to `13` as the first occurence of this property).

Maybe based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28182579/14776523), how to do this best with Python?

my idea: create a bool list for this
`[a>10 for a in l]` (which consists of `True` and `False` as sequence) , alternatively `l>10` yields an array somehow using   `numpy`?

Comment: Do you want the indexes of all numbers greater than 10?

Comment: What is the output that you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to negate the condition to get the last index that has `element <=10` using

```
l = np.array([12,13,14,10,13,14])
first_index = np.where(l<=10)[0][-1]+1 # yields the first index that satisfies the condition
```

One could first check for `len(np.where(...))`  to verify that the condition is violated at least once, else return 0 for first index.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate backwards through the list and catch the index of the first condition failure.  This prevents issues where several values fail...

```
In [51]: l                                                                                  
Out[51]: [12, 13, 14, 10, 13, 14]

In [52]: next((len(l) - idx for idx, val in enumerate(l[::-1]) if val <= 10), None)         
Out[52]: 4

In [53]: l = [12, 13, 10, 20, 10, 15]                                                       

In [54]: next((len(l) - idx for idx, val in enumerate(l[::-1]) if val <= 10), None)         
Out[54]: 5

In [55]: l = [23, 55]                                                                       

In [56]: next((len(l) - idx for idx, val in enumerate(l[::-1]) if val <= 10), None)         

In [57]:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [12,13,14,10,13,14]
i = len(l)
for i in reversed(l):
    condition = v > 10
    if not condition:
        break
    i -= 1
print(i)
# Output : 4
```

Be careful with the case of the last element of the list not satisfying the condition. The i value would be equal to len(l) wich is not a valid index for the list. It is up to you to choose how to manage that special case.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from end of the array :

```
def findStartOfMoreThan(l,limit):
    for i in range(len(l)-1, -1, -1):
        if l[i]<=limit :
            return i+1
    return (-1)
    
assert(findStartOfMoreThan([12,13,14,10,13,14],10) == 4)
assert(findStartOfMoreThan([12,13,14,10,13,14,15],10)==4)
assert(findStartOfMoreThan([0,12,13,14,10,13,14,15],10)==5)
assert(findStartOfMoreThan([0,12,13,14,10,13,14,15],13)==6)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
[l.index(item) for item in l if not item>10][-1]+1
```